# Picasso library can't show images into Volley NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso

I'm using NetworkImageView to display images.

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
```

And my adapter.java is here.

```
public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        card = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
        category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cate_view);
        location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_view);  
        imageview = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final NewsFeeds feeds = feedsList.get(position);
    //Pass the values of feeds object to Views
    holder.title.setText(feeds.getFeedName());
    holder.category.setText(feeds.getFeedCategory());
    holder.location.setText(feeds.getFeedLocation());
    //holder.imageview.setImageUrl(feeds.getImgURL(), NetworkController.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(feeds.getImgURL())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_user)
            .into(holder.imageview);
```

I am using Picasso library for display images. But it can't display images.

I am learning Android. Can anyone tell me what is the actual process? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have. other details showing perfectly except images.

Comment: Use `ImageView` instead. For `NetworkImageView`, if google, you will find something such as `NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
        ImageLoader mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl("http://yourserver/images/bnk123456789.jpg", mImageLoader);`